# Get a specific element from an array in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an array and I want to take specific element from it using directive (for example array[0]), but I don't understand how to achieve it. I realize that this is the basics of angularjs but I can't find anywhere a solution. Please help :)

Here's the array

```
    $scope.array = [
      {
        text: '1',
      },
      {
        text: '2',
      },
      {
        text: '3',
      }]
```

And I use that construction in a view

```
<div ng-repeat="element in array">
     <content></content>
</div>
```

And this is what contains that directive

```
<p>{{array.text}}</p>
```

Comment: You want to show element in <content> directive?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

In html : 
In content directive you will have to add
bindToController: {data: "="}

Comment: and then what should I write to call a specific element? 
I thought it should be something like <content array=array[1]>

Comment: no you just have to say <content data="element"></content>
At the time of execution, 1st time array[0] in data, 2nd time array[1], 3rd time array[2]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the same var in your directive instead of `data`

```
<div ng-repeat="element in array">
     <content></content>
</div>
```

directive:

```
<p>{{element.text}}</p>
```

If the directive is about `customer` data you should use `{{ customer.text }}`, if that is the case you can continue using the same scope like this ...

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in array">
     <content></content>
</div>
```

directive:

```
<p>{{customer.text}}</p>
```